Show that the linear map induced by a symmetric associative bilinear form of L is an L-module homomorphism
This is about exercise 9.10 in the book "Introduction to Lie Algebras" by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon.
Suppose that $\textbf{L}$ is a Lie algebra over $\textbf{C}$ and that $\beta$ is a symmetric, associative bilinear form of $\textbf{L}$. Show that $\beta$ induces a linear map $\theta: L \rightarrow L^{*}, \theta(x) = \beta(x,-)$. Where by $\beta(x,-)$ we mean the map $y \mapsto \beta(x,y)$. Viewing both $L$ and $L^{*}$ as L-modules, show that $\theta$ is an L-module homomorphism. (The L-module structure of $L^{*}$ is given by Exercise 7.12).
$L^{*}$ means dual space in this book.
My confusion is around the hint about Exercise 7.12. In 7.12(i), a dual space $V^{*}$ is made into an L-module by defining $(x \cdot \theta)(v) = -\theta(x \cdot v)$ for $x \in L, \theta \in V^{*}, v \in V$.
Here, if I define the dual space similarly as 7.12: $(x \cdot \theta)(y) = -\theta(x \cdot y)$ for $x \in L, \theta \in L^{*}, y \in L$,
then $\theta(x \cdot y) = -x \space \theta(y) \neq x \space \theta(y)$, unless some term becomes zero, wouldn't that contradict the L-module homomorphism definition immediately?
L-module homomorphism is defined in 7.6 as a linear map $\theta: V \rightarrow W$ such that $\theta(x \cdot v) = x \cdot \theta(v)$ for all $v \in V$ and $x \in L$.
What would be the correct approach for this problem? Thanks a lot.
Exercise 9.12 depends on 9.11, which depends on 9.10. That's why I'd like to make sure I understand 9.10 before proceeding.

Let's say $L$ is a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, and $V, W$ are $L$-modules, and recall the definitions:

The linear map $f : V \to W$ is a homomorphism of $L$-modules if $f(x \cdot v) = x \cdot f(v)$ for all $x \in L$, $v \in V$.
The dual space $V^*$ becomes an $L$-module via $(x \cdot \varphi)(v) = - \varphi(x \cdot v)$ for $x \in L$, $v \in V$, and $\varphi \in V^*$.
The tensor product $V \otimes W$ becomes an $L$-module via $x \cdot (v \otimes w) = (x \cdot v)\otimes w + v \otimes (x \cdot w)$.
The base field $\mathbb{C}$ is a trivial $L$-module, $x \cdot 1 = 0$.
$L$ itself is an $L$-module under the adjoint action $x \cdot y = [x, y]$.
A symmetric bilinear form $\beta: L \times L \to \mathbb{C}$ is called associative or invariant if it defines a homomorphism of $L$-modules $L \otimes L \to \mathbb{C}$. This is equivalent to requiring that $\beta(x\cdot y, z) + \beta(y, x \cdot z) = 0$

Now, let's focus on our invariant symmetric bilinear form $\beta : L \times L \to \mathbb{C}$. Define the fix-the-left-argument map $\beta_L$ by
$$ \beta_L: L \to L^*, \quad \beta_L(x)(y) = \beta(x, y).$$
We want to argue that this is a homomorphism, so check:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta_L(x \cdot y)(z)
&= \beta(x \cdot y, z) && \text{definition of $\beta_L$} \\
&= \beta([x, y], z) && \text{definition of adjoint action} \\
&= -\beta([y, x], z) && \text{antisymmetry of Lie bracket} \\
&= -\beta(y, [x, z]) && \text{invariant bilinear form }\\
&= -\beta_L(y)(x \cdot z)  && \text{definition of adjoint action} \\
&= (x \cdot \beta_L(y))(z) && \text{module structure on $L^*$} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Since the above holds for all $x, y, z \in L$, we have that $\beta_L(x \cdot y) = x \cdot \beta_L(y)$ for all $x, y \in L$, so $\beta_L: L \to L^*$ is a homomorphism of $L$-modules.

I am missing point 3 and 6. I probably have misunderstood the definition of associative bilinear form homomorphism.

And I did not recognize the difference between dot product and L-module action of $L$ itself: $x \cdot y \rightarrow [x, y]$. lol
